# Updating ElasticSearch on Azure DevOps

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020

i am trying to upgrade ES on my Azure DevOps 2020, ES is installed on a separate Server and therefore cannot be updated, it has to be reinstalled and i am following the [instructions from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?view=azure-devops-2020#upgrade-search). i first run the uninstall command `Configure-TFSSearch.ps1 -Operation remove` then the install command provided on the page above as well but the version being installed is the same as before, the old unsupported one. I looked into the Search Service Package folder and the files there are related to the current old version, i tried copying the elasticsearch installation file to the search service package folder and running the script again but it said

```
[ERROR]: Elasticsearch does not exist at: C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2020\Search\zip\modules\..\elasticsearchv6.2.zip
```

So it is looking for the the version 6.2 where i want to install the latest 7.16.3v. How do i get the search service package files related to the latest ES version.

I have also tried [this](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2020/11/azure-devops-server-upgrade.html) and [this](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2020/11/azure-devops-server-upgrade.html) with no luck. any help please. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure DevOps only supports the modified version of Elastic Search it ships with. For Azure DevOps Server 2019 and 2020 that's elastic search v6.2.

With the log4shell vulnerability found in log4j, [it's likely the next update pack for Azure DevOps Server 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-and-azure-devops-server-and-the-log4j-vulnerability/#comment-3024) and the next major version of Azure DevOps Server, 2022, will ship with a much more recent version of Elastic Search.

Manually upgrading Elastic Search to a version other than the one shipping with your version of Azure DevOps Server is not supported, undocumented and will likely cause problems.

If you're trying to protect yourself against log4shell, you can find guidance here:

- https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-patch-for-log4j-vulnerability/
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-and-azure-devops-server-and-the-log4j-vulnerability/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511

Official patches just got dropped:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-server-and-team-foundation-server-patches/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511

Comment: Well, that clears things up for sure! I was trying to update it because of the log4j vulnerability! Thank you for sparing me more hours of research!

Comment: Update coming soon hopefully. It's taking much longer than I was expecting. Then again, they are likely having to release an patch for TFS2018, Azure DevOps Server 2019, 2020 and fix 2022 before Release. That's a lot of test work to make sure nothing breaks. And the release shouldn't be breaking hardware compatibility if at all possible. I do not envy the team having to roll out these fixes.

Comment: The official patches just got dropped. Link added above.